# EXCEL Count unique values if criteria met

Tags: excel, excel-formula, unique, countif

I am trying to achieve a formula that will count unique Batch codes in the same date. So for example Column B (Serial no.) should increase a value if above if any of the rows above with the same date has a different batch code. This is part of a larger code

The code I have so far does quite the opposite and I've tried interchanging the criteria etc. but nothing seems to give me the result that I am after.

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:A2,A2,$D$2:D2,"<>"&D2)>0,TEXT(COUNTIFS($A$2:A2,A2,$D$2:D2,D2),"00"),TEXT(COUNTIFS($A$2:A2,A2,$D$2:D2,D2),"00"))
```

Here is a link to an example spreadsheet

I have added a column to show what the expected values should be.

Thank you in advance

Comment: we.tl/t-sVSfbi8G9c
A link to an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could try:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)>1,IF(COUNTIFS(A$2:A2,A2,D$2:D2,D2)>1,MAXIFS(B$1:B1,A$1:A1,A2,D$1:D1,D2),MAXIFS(B$1:B1,A$1:A1,A2)+1),1)
```

I'd then use custom number formatting to create the leading zero with: `00`.