# How to find the maximum count of cells in excel having values in a range continuously?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a huge data collected daily on our device. The data has 3 columns.
Col1 is Date
Col2 is Time
Col3 is Data Value

My task is to find how many time the value in Col3 falls between specific range and report the "maximum continuous occurrence" for that day.

So if the table is like below,

| Date | Time | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1Jan23 | 5am | 6 |
| 1Jan23 | 6am | 7 |
| 1Jan23 | 7am | 5 |
| 1Jan23 | 8am | 0 |
| 1Jan23 | 9am | 2 |
| 1Jan23 | 10am | 7 |
| 1Jan23 | 11am | 5 |
| 1Jan23 | 12pm | 0 |
| 2Jan23 | 5am | 0 |
| 2Jan23 | 6am | 1 |
| 2Jan23 | 7am | 6 |
| 2Jan23 | 8am | 5 |
| 2Jan23 | 9am | 6 |
| 2Jan23 | 10am | 7 |
| 2Jan23 | 11am | 5 |
| 2Jan23 | 12pm | 0 |
| 3Jan23 | 5am | 1 |
| 3Jan23 | 6am | 6 |
| 3Jan23 | 7am | 6 |
| 3Jan23 | 8am | 1 |
| 3Jan23 | 9am | 2 |
| 3Jan23 | 10am | 5 |
| 3Jan23 | 11am | 1 |
| 3Jan23 | 12pm | 9 |

and if I want to count maximum how many times the value was between 4 & 8 in column "Value", the answer I should get as :

| Date | Max Count for Day |
| --- | --- |
| 1Jan23 | 3 |
| 2Jan23 | 5 |
| 3Jan23 | 2 |

This is just an example. I have data of daily values for almost a year and need a way to show just maximum continuous count of value within specific range for each date.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EXCEL Count unique values if criteria met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71508567/excel-count-unique-values-if-criteria-met)

Comment: No. My requirement is little different. I want to count maximum how many times values in column for a day is between a specific range.

Comment: If you have Excel 365 you need to use function UNIQUE, FILTER and COUNTIFS to get your desired output. FILTER will allow you to get values only from a specific date in column1, then UNIQUE will return unique values on that filtered range. Finally COUNTIFS, will count how many values are inside the range 4-8

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns The question needs to calculate the maximum and **continuous** values in a range, I don't think we can use `COUNTIFS` because it doesn't consider the requirement of being continuous. Check my answer below for more details.

Comment: @DavidLeal You are totally right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll preface this by saying there is probably a way to do this without VBA, especially in newer versions of Excel so you might be better off waiting for another answer.

Anyway, this UDF should work:

```vb
Function continuousCount(ByVal rng As Range, ByVal testedDate As String, ByVal min As Double, ByVal max As Double) As Long
    Dim mcc As Long, ccc As Long, val As Double, currentDate As String, dataArr() As Variant
    dataArr = rng
    For i = 1 To UBound(dataArr)
        val = dataArr(i, 3)
        currentDate = dataArr(i, 1)
        
        If currentDate = testedDate Then
            If val >= min And val <= max Then
                ccc = ccc + 1
            Else
                If ccc > mcc Then
                    mcc = ccc
                    ccc = 0
                End If
            End If
        End If
        

    Next i
    
    If ccc > mcc Then mcc = ccc
    
    continuousCount = mcc
End Function
```

You can use it in your worksheet like so (I named the table "data"):

[image]

I used a pivot table to get the list of dates and put the formula in the column next to it.

It is rather inelegant and I still believe there is a way to do this without VBA in newer versions of excel as you can do pretty much everything with built-in functions. I only have Excel 2010 so this is the best I can do.

Comment: Thanks. How if there are more line items with date ranging from 1jan23 to 31jan23. And if I want to display a table having 1 column as date and against that maximum continuous count for that day?

Comment: @Adikul I'm not sure I follow. Can you perhaps update the table in your question so that it looks like what you are describing here?

Comment: Updated table and expected answer in my question.

Comment: @Adikul I modified the answer to fit your needs. Now the formula accepts 4 arguments. Your table with data (needs to have 3 columns in the same order you showed in your question), the date you want to check, minimum and maximum. It's probably not the best solution but it should work OK.

Comment: when you say you named table as "data", does it mean it's excel sheet name? Somehow the script throwing me error "There is Problem with this Formula"

Comment: @Adikul no, I copied your data and converted it to a table (select everything and press ctrl+T) and named the table "data". You don't have to do this, you can just feed it the range. So it can be something like =continuousCount(A2:C25,"1Jan23",4,8) Note that my Excel uses semi colons as argument separator and yours probably uses commas. So use commas :)

Comment: excellent. semicolon was the issue. thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following using Excel formulas, assuming *no Excel version constraints per the tags listed in the question*.

```
=LET(A,A2:A25,C,C2:C25,ux,UNIQUE(A),min,F1,max,H1,
 out, BYROW(ux, LAMBDA(u,LET(f, FILTER(C, A=u),
  MAX(SCAN(0,f, LAMBDA(ac,x, IF(AND(x>=min, x<=max),ac+1,0))))))),HSTACK(ux,out))
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

Iterate over all unique dates via `BYROW` and for each unique date(`u`), it filters **Value** items for a given date, then uses `SCAN` to count the number of continuous values within a given range and finds the maximum value (maximum number of continuous values for a given date). Finally, `HSTACK` generates the output in the desired format. The formula assumes the input data is sorted by date (as in the sample of the question), otherwise, it must be adjusted.